# Exclude a file /directory in fileset tag before executing a target

Tags: java, ant, jar, build

I am writing an Ant buildfile for a project structured like this:

```
build.xml
    | child_build1.xml
    | child_build2.xml
        | calling generated jar file from child_build_1.xml
```

Calling Ant using the command

```
ant -f build clean build-project
```

here clean and build-project are targets.
child_build2.xml generates a jar file which includes some other jar files with child_build1.jar file.

I am using a temp folder to place jar files generated by build and generating an rpm. 
To include internal jars I am using a fileset to include jars.

```
<path id="classpath.migrate">
     <path refid="classpath"/>
     <fileset dir="${parent}/test">
         <include name="test1.jar"/>
     </fileset>
     <fileset dir="${parent}/bin">
         <include name="xxx.jar"/>
         <include name="yyyy.jar"/>
     </fileset>
</path>

<target name="build-project">
    <mkdir dir="${parent}/bin/" />
    <mkdir dir="${parent}/lib/" />

    ...creating of parent directory and jar creation logic
</target>
<target name="clean">
    ...clearing all the file
</target>
```

I have declared values in a build.properties file which I have included in property tag.

While triggering the "clean" target Ant tries to parse, but fails to find ${parent} folder. Actually the parent folder ${parent} will be generated in "build" target.
I am generating the rpm using an rpmbuild command from a script. Script intern calls rpmbuild with spec file. Ant script is called in spec file.

build.properties:

```
root.dir                =       rootdirectory
test.dir                =       ${root.dir}/test/
dist.dir                =       ${build.dir}/dist/
```

In spec Ant file is called with parent directory value. So there is no hard coded value.

Is there any way to exclude the checking mechanism and directly exeucte the target or skip the errors in fileset?

There is an attribute erroronmissingdir in fileset to skip the error in clear target.

Comment: have you defined parent property? If yes where? Is it in same build file? Can you show that as well.

Comment: question updated with the properties file and other stuff.

Comment: i still dont see where you specified parent property. Also in what order you are calling these targets.

Comment: parent directory is passed from script where rpmcommand is called. i am calling build file " ant -f build.xml clean build-project" so clean will  be called first and then build-project. Everything is a runtime value

Comment: I assume that your `clean` target has a `<delete>` in it. Can you add `failonerror="false"` to `<delete>` so the Ant script doesn't fail if `${parent}` is missing?

Comment: Before clean target execution, ant start parsing from starting of the file ie)<fileset>. Also i am not deleting {parent} directory in clean target. In fileset tag, {parent} directory is missing because of this ant script fails.

Comment: use below code   before </project>  as :   <target name="clean" depends="build-project" description="..."> and you can add depends attribute in target also.